# pip install vprof fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to install the package vprof from PyCharm but I'm getting the error:

> Collecting vprof
>
> Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/2b/5b690c8bd73231216c82180b7b162cf433dd98d6212b19a7374c5cf09622/vprof-0.36.1.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\vprof\setup.py",
>   line 12, in 
>           from pip.download import PipSession
>       ImportError: No module named download
>
> ---
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\vprof\

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Other packages like Theano, NLTK or astor are getting installed without a problem. 
I'm using pip version 10.0.1 and python 2.7 and PyCharm 2018.1.2.

Searching for the error "No module named download" didn't get me any solutions.

Comment: Try upgrading `setuptools`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vprof` imports `pip` which is very much discouraged. And it uses the old API from `pip` before version 10. You have to downgrade `pip` back to version 9:

```
pip install -U 'pip>=9,<10'
```

Also I recommend to report the bug at the `vprof` issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install -U 'pip>=9,<10'
pip install vprof
```

did the job for me