# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.download' when trying to install Python package for Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, django-2.0

When trying to install Numpy and other packages using pip. I get a message saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.download'`. Anyone know any possible solutions for this? I'm currently running on Python3. I've had a look at similar problems but no solutions seem to work. E.g. ["pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

```
pip3 install 'django-numpy==1.0'
Collecting django-numpy==1.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/15/22ea119379010455ee91c3ee2f76da207fbd342f5277305da3ad660a0a13/django-numpy-1.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/pz/d28llk412ss8ptwv5znkhv1m0000gn/T/pip-install-kwd6b6us/django-numpy/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from pip.download import PipSession
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.download'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/pz/d28llk412ss8ptwv5znkhv1m0000gn/T/pip-install-kwd6b6us/django-numpy/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install vprof fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113927/pip-install-vprof-fails)

Comment: The package is different (`vprof` vs `django-numpy`) but the problem is the same: `setup.py` imports `pip` which is forbidden. The solution is also the same: downgrade `pip` to version 9.0.3. And report the problem to their issue tracker.

Comment: Cheers @phd that worked a charm!

Comment: @phd please answer this question so the author could accept it as correct

Comment: @LjubisaLivac I've answered at the linked dup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pip version should be reduced to 9.0.1 `pip install pip==9.0.1`

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to update an old Python package using this code, `from pip.download import PipSession`, this snippet can replace it

```
try:  # pip >= 10
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
except ImportError:  # pip <= 9.0.3
    from pip.download import PipSession
```

(derived from this similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49867265/148585)